# Почему после установки ramus ярлыка на рабочем столе нет, а через пуск найти ramus не получается?

Tags: windows, windows-10, моделирование, анализ

У меня Windows 10. Я установил `Ramus`, но ярлыка нет ни на рабочем столе, ни в панели "Пуск", причём если ввести в поиск в том же "Пуске", найти тоже ничего не получается.

Переход в папку приложения также проблемы не решает, так как при попадании туда я обнаруживают только кучу `jre`-файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Как казалось, нужна была Java Runtime Environment: http://java-runtime.ru/download